# Is there a way were we can specify two services for single context path in istio virtual service?

Tags: kubernetes, microservices, istio, istio-gateway, istio-operator

I have two different micro-services running in same name space, both have same context path (ex - my/context/path), further controllers are different in both of them, for example service one supports - my/context/path/service1 and service2 supports my/context/path/service2
now when i defined vs like this, its always redirecting to the service1, is there a possible way to achieve this?
below is my VS:

```
        apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
        kind: VirtualService
        metadata:
        name: test-service
        namespace: ns-ns
        spec:
         gateways:
         - gateway.ns-ns
        hosts:
         - '*'
       http:
       - match:
        - uri:
          prefix: /my/context/path
        route:
        - destination:
            host: service1.ns-ns.svc.cluster.local
            port:
              number: 9000
      - route:
        - destination:
            host: service2.ns-ns.svc.cluster.local
            port:
              number: 9000
```

I also tried below VS, but this also seems to redirect to first service.

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
  name: test-service
  namespace: ns-ns
spec:
  gateways:
  - gateway.ns-ns
  hosts:
  - '*'
  http:
    - match:
      - uri:
          prefix: /my/context/path
      route:
        - destination:
            host: service1.ns-ns.svc.cluster.local
            port:
              number: 9000
    - match:        
      - uri:
          prefix: /my/context/path/service2
      route:
        - destination:
            host: service2.ns-ns.svc.cluster.local
            port:
              number: 9000
```

i am not sure if this is achievable or not, or do i need to separate the context part of both the services?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The routes are matched in order. Thus you need to start from the most specific to the most generic. e.g.

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
  name: test-service
  namespace: ns-ns
spec:
  gateways:
  - gateway.ns-ns
  hosts:
  - '*'
  http:
    - match:        
      - uri:
          prefix: /my/context/path/service2
      route:
        - destination:
            host: service2.ns-ns.svc.cluster.local
            port:
              number: 9000
    - match:
      - uri:
          prefix: /my/context/path
      route:
        - destination:
            host: service1.ns-ns.svc.cluster.local
            port:
              number: 9000
```

Comment: rearranging the order worked, Thanks at lot, but if in case all my services have initial context path same ('my/context/path') can't we define multiple routes in the same prefix? like in the first VS i shared.

Comment: You can if you use different hostnames. i.e. app1.example.com, app2.example.com, and so on. Another option, if you can modify the clients to make requests prefixed with the app name, then you can rewrite paths. for e.g. if `/app1/my/path` matches, then rewrite to /my/path and forward to the server service with the correct path. I recommend using different hosts.